# Is it possible to control an attribute like 'readonly' via a model?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way, through a model, to control the value of an attribute like 'readonly', one that doesn't accept a value that can be assigned to it? (I am aware that readonly="readonly" is valid XHTML but it doesn't help).

Below, 'name' and 'value' can be changed through a model, but how would it be possible for 'readonly'?

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [ng-readonly](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) directive:

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" ng-readonly="expression">
```

This will make the input readonly for any truthy value of `expression`.

Answer (score 2):

[ngReadonly](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) does that:

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" ng-readonly="isCountryReadOnly">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many boolean attributes with corresponding directives, namely `selected`, `checked`, `disabled`, `readonly`, `required`, and `open`.  If you need some sort of custom boolean attribute, you'll have to add a watch and set it manually:

```
scope.$watch(attr['myAttrName'], function (value) {
    attr.$set('attrName', !!value);
});
```

This will evaluate the expression contained in a custom attribute and display the desired boolean attribute if the expression evaluates to a truthy value.